# Youtube data api error in signed apk?

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to implement the functionality of add subscription to youtube channel from android app.

i already done with :

1. register app on developer console. -Done
2. package name and SHA-1 certificate fingerprint. -Done
   [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IsBA.png)
3. Google account account authentication with "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube" . -Done

Note : functionality is working fine in debug mode.

Issue: when i create a signed apk for publishing app on play store then subscribe button not working throw different errors each time .

i.e  **With unrestricted api key** :

```
W/System.err: {
"c" : 0,
   "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
     "reason" : "required",
     "message" : "Required parameter: part",
    "locationType" : "parameter",
   "location" : "part"
   } ],
   "code" : 400,
   "message" : "Required parameter: part"
 }
```

Here is the code that Im doing

```
  // Initialize credentials and service object.
        mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES)).setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff());

 HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();

                    JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();


                    YouTube mService = new YouTube.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, mCredential)
                            .setApplicationName(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                            .setYouTubeRequestInitializer(new YouTubeRequestInitializer(Config.KEY))
                            .build();


 channelId = myListModel.getYoutubeChannelId();
// Create a resourceId that identifies the channel ID.
                        ResourceId resourceId = new ResourceId();
                        resourceId.setChannelId(channelId);
                        resourceId.setKind("youtube#channel");


 // Create a snippet that contains the resourceId.
                        SubscriptionSnippet snippet = new SubscriptionSnippet();
                        snippet.setResourceId(resourceId);

                        // Create a request to add the subscription and send the request.
                        // The request identifies subscription metadata to insert as well
                        // as information that the API server should return in its response.
                        Subscription subscription = new Subscription();

                        subscription.setSnippet(snippet);

                        YouTube.Subscriptions.Insert subscriptionInsert = mService.subscriptions().insert("snippet,contentDetails", subscription);

                        try {
                            Subscription returnedSubscription = subscriptionInsert.execute();

                            // Print information from the API response.
                            System.out.println("\n================== Returned Subscription ==================\n");

                            System.out.println("  - Id: " + returnedSubscription.getId());

                            System.out.println("  - Title: " + returnedSubscription.getSnippet().getTitle());

                            addSubscriber(myListModel);

                        } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException mLastError) {

                            startActivityForResult(mLastError.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);

                        }

                    } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
                        System.err.println("GoogleJsonResponseException code: " + e.getDetails().getCode() + " : "
                                + e.getDetails().getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();


                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.err.println("IOException: " + e.getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    } catch (Throwable t) {
                        System.err.println("Throwable: " + t.getMessage());
                        t.printStackTrace();

                    }
```

Comment: Have you got the solution